# Assembly program refuses to accept a larger number

Tags: assembly, runtime, large-data

I am trying to write a program that applies Ulam's conjecture to a number. I have the program working, however it refuses to accept the numbers 38836 and 38838. When these numbers are entered, it gives me the error: NUMBER OUT OF RANGE TRY AGAIN. The stack is at 256, and the variable used is a DW type. I am brand new to assembly and so I apologize if I did not include proper information, or am overlooking something simple, but I am very stuck. Here is what I think may be relevant to my problem.

```
            DOSSEG
            .MODEL  SMALL, BASIC, FARSTACK

            EXTRN   GETDEC:FAR
            EXTRN   NEWLINE:FAR
            EXTRN   PUTDEC:FAR
            EXTRN   PUTSTRNG:FAR

            .STACK  256


    .DATA
NUM           DW      ?
CNT           DW      0
PROMPT        DB      'Enter an integer: '
TOTAL         DB      'Number Total: '
FLOWMSG       DB      'OVERFLOW      '

       .CODE

ULAMS:                      
  MOV    AX,SEG DGROUP        
  MOV    ES,AX

    LEA      DI,PROMPT
    MOV      CX,18
    CALL     PUTSTRNG
    CALL     GETDEC

    MOV  NUM,AX
    MOV  CNT,0

    --->Rest of program cut for brevity<-----
```

Comment: Are you sure that GETDEC allows for such large numbers to be entered?

Comment: _"it gives me the error: NUMBER OUT OF RANGE TRY AGAIN"_. I don't see that string in the code you've posted, so from where is that output?

Comment: GETDEC is the command we were told to enter, as we are only modifying code given to us for the most part. we do not currently know of another way to collect data. The NUMBER OUT OF RANGE happens during runtime. the prompt for the number is displayed, and upon entering a number like 38836, the error is then displayed

Comment: Where does GETDEC put the number that was entered, when it works?

Comment: the ax register, which is then placed into the variable NUM

Comment: Assuming a signed integer, what is the largest value that fits in 16 bits?

Comment: I tried changing the code you suggested, but it didnt fix anything =/ To be honest, im not sure what those are for, our teacher basically never mentioned it past, "setting up the registers" with no other explanation

Comment: So in order to fit the value, the program needs to accept unsigned integers, yet I am lost on how to make it do this!

Answer (score 0):

If GETDEC puts the entered value in register AX, which is a 16-bit register, then there is nothing you can do to make GETDEC accept a number that doesn't fit in a 16-bit register.

You'll have to fashion some other way of entering such large numbers; for example, reading in a string and computing the number it represents.

Comment: When i asked around in class, people said they had no issue with it. If it required some work around as you suggest, that may have garnered a noteworthy response, i would think. They simply suggested changing the stack size or the NUM data type. Maybe it must be unsigned? however im not sure how to change the code segment to account for unsigned

Comment: So it appears I need this program to accept an unsigned integer, yet I cannot figure out how to do so. If anyone could provide some help in making this program accept unsigned integers, it would be so appreciated

Comment: Maybe you could ask someone in the class who had no problem how they are calling GETDEC (or if they are calling something else).

Comment: Apparently according to the duplicate question the function they needed to call was getdec$ for unsigned integers