# Converting a program to accept unsigned integer

Tags: assembly, unsigned-integer

I have written this program to perform ulam's conjecture on an entered integer, however when entering a number such as 38836, it exceeds the bounds for a 16 bit signed integer. I believe using unsigned would fix my issue, however I cannot figure out how to adjust this code segment to accept an unsigned integer. Any Help would be very much appreciated!

```
            DOSSEG
            .MODEL  SMALL, BASIC, FARSTACK

            EXTRN   GETDEC:FAR
            EXTRN   NEWLINE:FAR
            EXTRN   PUTDEC:FAR
            EXTRN   PUTSTRNG:FAR

            .STACK  256


    .DATA
NUM           DW      ?
CNT           DW      0
PROMPT        DB      'Enter an integer: '
TOTAL         DB      'Number Total: '
FLOWMSG       DB      'OVERFLOW      '

       .CODE

ULAMS:                      
  MOV    AX,SEG DGROUP        
  MOV    ES,AX

    LEA      DI,PROMPT
    MOV      CX,18
    CALL     PUTSTRNG
    CALL     GETDEC

    MOV  NUM,AX
    MOV  CNT,0

    --->Rest of program cut for brevity<-----
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no difference between unsigned and signed integers in assembly language. The only difference is how you interpret the data and the flags that get set during arithmetic functions.

Comment: You have not shown the relevant parts of the program. But in 80x86 (if that is what it seems to be) there is a different set of branch instructions that you use for signed and unsigned arithmetic.

Comment: The issue is that upon entering 38836, i get an error message, and it wont allow me to enter it. The assignment requires that this number work, and therefore be entered utilizing unsigned integers, yet I am at a loss as for how to do that.

Comment: In that case you must post the relevant code for `GETDEC`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly program refuses to accept a larger number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977190/assembly-program-refuses-to-accept-a-larger-number)

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case, this issue was fixed by using a seperate command that specified the input as unsigned, called GETDEC$. This fixed the issue and allowed the range of integers for unsigned 16 bit, rather than signed.